# Use Pandas in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Trying to create a basic Python Function and use it in Azure Function App(Consumption based). Used the HTTP Template via VS Code and able to use and get it deployed on Azure. However when I try to use "Pandas" in the logic, I get the error which I am not able to rectify. Me being a rookie in Python.  Can you suggest how to rectify ?

Tool Used : VS Code , Azure Functions Tools
Python version installed locally : 3.8.5
Azure Function App Python Version : 3.8

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the `pandas` module hasn't been installed in your function on azure. You need to add the `pandas` module into your local `requirements.txt` and then deploy the function from local to azure. It will install the modules according to the lines in `requirements.txt`.

You can run this command in "Terminal" window to generate the `pandas` line in your `requirements.txt` automatically.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

After running the command above, your `requirements.txt` should be like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shen for the quick response.  Why don't you create a blog with these nitty-gritty of Azure ? :-)

Comment: Hi @Akshay The official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python) has already shown the information about `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue
Pandas was in the requirements.txt
But I was handling excel files and had to add specific pandas dependencies, because they were not automatically loaded with only pandas in the requirements.txt

Check the docs what you need

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34536489)